# Suggest a model for segmenting a time series

Tags: time-series, hidden-markov-model

[image: Example time series]

Hi all, I have a time series that looks like above. I'm interested in segmenting it into the numbering listed.

I've tried using a hidden Markov model, but the versions I can find with multiple observations per state (different state lengths) usually assume the y's (data) are conditionally independent given the states. I think that is too restrictive here with the semicircles and triangle shapes. It's also not clear how to set up the emission distributions for each state, so it's not clear how to write down a likelihood.

Dynamic time warping looks promising here. I can verify the similar states are close to each other. But it's not clear how to proceed with it.

Comment: What do these numbers represent? A non constant value?

Comment: @user2974951 The numbers are just for indexing the unique states. State 3 - semicircle - shows up twice and in those locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at fig 31 of [a]. The data looks almost identical, and the task is the same. That is the SOTA solution.

eamonn

[a] https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10618-014-0345-2

Data Mining and Knowledge Discovery March 2015, Volume 29, Issue 2, pp 358–399.
Using the minimum description length to discover the intrinsic cardinality and dimensionality of time series